# Linkup javascript in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

we can link a CSS file in HTML file. But how can I link JavaScript file in an html file?
Suppose if we link a CSS file we write 
Like that how can I link a JavaScript file?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" src="style.css">

Comment: http://javascript.info/tutorial/adding-script-html#external-scripts

Comment: For web technology documentation try adding "w3c" OR "mdn" OR "stackoverflow" to you search string. Search "w3c script" for example.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) tag.

```
<script src="/some/server/resource.js"></script>
```

Note that the `type` attribute is no longer necessary.  You used to write it as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/a/b/c.js"></script>
```

Bear in mind that *where* you put the `<script>` tag can impact how the JavaScript behaves as it can block the DOM while loading if added to the `<head>`.  The differences about what placement changes what is an entirely different question.

Answer (score 0):

you can link a javascript file in a HTML document using the **script** tag.

Here is an example: 
`<script src="myscripts.js"></script>`

Here is some more information about this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

You can also write javascript inside script tags like normal.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<script src="url_to_your_script.js"></script>` tag to your html file, preferably in the head tag.

For more information, visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="your_file_name.js"></script>
```

Add this code at the end of your body tag. 
Happy Coding:)